# Cordova backbutton with cordova background mode

Tags: android, cordova

I have this great Cordova plugin installed in my app to keep it running in the background.

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git
```

The plugin creates the object cordova.plugins.backgroundMode with the following methods:

```
backgroundMode.enable
backgroundMode.disable
backgroundMode.isEnabled
backgroundMode.isActive
backgroundMode.getDefaults
backgroundMode.setDefaults
backgroundMode.configure
backgroundMode.onactivate
backgroundMode.ondeactivate
backgroundMode.onfailure
```

Now I am using cordova backbutton event I wanted on backbutton send the app to backgroundMode like this but it doesn't work.

```
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
 function onBackKeyDown() {
 // Handle the back button
backgroundMode.enable();
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: how you know that it does not work? did you get any errors when calling enable of cordova.plugins.backgroundMode after backbutton event is triggered?

Comment: I didn't get any errors but there is no action nothing happens. I might be getting errors but not visible because I just compile it from intel xdk to apk then check it with my phone, I've replaced the line backgroundMode.enable(); with navigator.exit() it works but I don't want to exit the app I wanted to leverage the backgroundMode plugin.

Comment: then you really have to use a logger to print all activities/errors that might occur and for the plugin it states that it keeps all connections open while in background so did you check for internet activities of your phone when your app is in background?

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        // Android customization
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text:'Doing heavy tasks.'});
        // Enable background mode
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

        // Called when background mode has been activated
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Modify the currently displayed notification
                cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({
                    text:'Running in background for more than 5s now.'
                });
            }, 5000);
        }
    }, false);
```